# Is this the right way to view this matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am a little shaky in matrix algebra, and I would like to double check if something is correct.

We have that for each $1 \le i \le n,$ we have $a_i^*B=0.$ This is equivalent to the matrix equation 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1^*\\
\vdots \\
a_n^*
\end{bmatrix} B=0
$$
Is the best way to view this, the following? View the first matrix as a $n \times 1$ block matrix, and view $B$ as a $1 \times 1$ block matrix. Then, if we multiply, we get that the product is 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1^* B\\
\vdots \\
a_n^* B
\end{bmatrix}=0
$$
which means is equivalent to $a_i^*B=0$ for each $i$. Is this the right way to view this, or is there a better way?

Comment: For me it's fine.

Comment: I would not say it is the 'right' way, I would say that is is a perfectly reasonable way. I like the quote attributed to von Neumann: "Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them".

Comment: @copper.hat Are there other ways? It is taking me a while to get used to these matrix manipulations haha

Comment: For me, focusing on the components sort of misses the point. I would think of the above as the equation $A^* B = 0$ rather than component wise. From this I see that we must have ${\cal R}B \subset \ker A$, whereas (for me), thinking of the components makes it hard to see this perspective.

Comment: @Ripi2 Shouldn't the product be $n \times 1$?

Comment: Right, nx1. I delete my previous comment.